# Process a text file line by line using parallelism but preserving order

Tags: java

I need to process the content of a plain text file line by line.

Since processing every single line requires some time-consuming processing (access to external resources), I'd like to execute it concurrently.

I could easily do that with a ThreadPoolExecutor but the problem is that I need to write the output maintaining the input order (even if I know that this would be non-optimal from a CPU usage standpoint).

Another constraint is that the input file could be *huge*, so keeping it all in memory in some sort of structure, is not an option.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the typical Producer Consumer pattern.

1) A thread reading the input file and creating a block of work. This block can have one line from the file or for efficiency (depending upon the use case) more than one. Each block has a monotonically increasing ascending order id.

2) A thread pool works on the block of tasks created/ submitted the step above. Result of the processing is written to a priority queue (sorted based on the order id).

3) A thread reads from this priority queue - this step also needs to maintain a counter of the last task it read. So if the head of queue is 3 and last task had a sequence of 1, it needs to wait for task 2 to arrive.

The same can also be implemented in a event driven way using callbacks. There will be some memory requirements in step 3; for example event arrives for 1, then 3, 4 and then 2. So 3 and 4 need to be kept in memory till results of block 2 arrive.

Comment: thanks! this was the first implementation I tried but I was not very satisftied because pulling the right block from the queue was a bit tricky and it was not a very clean design. I am wondering if there is a cleaner pattern for such a problem.